# Find radius of fixed length arc of a circle in a bounding box when the circle intersects the edge of the bounding box

Tags: math

I have a bounding Box that is represented as a Cartesian starting point(0,0) with a width and height.

I have a circle with centre point that can be anywhere within the bounding box.
the circumference of the circle is fixed.

When the circle intersects the edge of the bounding box an arc is formed. 
This new arc has to have a length = to the circumference of the original circle.

The location of the centre of the circle is is known there for the distance from the centre to the edge of the bounding box is know.

as you move closer to the edge of the bound box the radius of the circle must increase to keep the arc length the same

the start and stop points of the arc are unknown as the radius is unknown.

This is where I'm stuck. knowing only the distance from the bounding box and the fixed length of the arc how can I find the radius of the circle ?

I have drawn an image to represent the question but I'm unable to post due to lack of reputation.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated as I have spent many days trying to figure this out.

What I am trying to achieve is a radial menu with fixed number of items (of a fixed size) can be displayed around a centre point. the fixed length is a calculated length that all menu items can fit around.

I am implementing this in .net but for the sake of this query its purely a Math question.

Edit: here is image of the issue:

[image: Illustration]

Comment: You say "When the circle intersects the edge of the bounding box an arc is formed."  How exactly is this arc formed?

Comment: my describing the problem is most likely why I cant find the answer apologies:
If the circle is less than the radius distance from an edge of the bounding box what remains inside the bounding box is an arc. hence its no longer a circle we are interested in its the arc that's "formed" probably not the right word but i hope that helps

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as you already stated, this is pretty much a pure math question, not specifically programming-related, and as such better asked on [the Math Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1. If it is purely a Math question you should post it at math.stackexchange rather than here. 2. If the circle's center is closer than R (circle's radius) to TWO adjacent sides of the rectangle, but not closer than R/sqrt(2), then TWO arcs result from the clipping. How do you define which one you consider? 3. You certainly know the circumference of the circle for given radius R. Radius R minus the yellow distance is a sagitta of the remaining arc - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_(geometry) Having that you can calculate the remaining arc's length, then solve for R.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I'm not looking for the arc length as that is fixed. 
what I need is the radius of an arc that creates an arc of the fixed length I desire.
where the start and stop points of the arc are along the edge bounds.
Where the centre point of the arc is X away from the edge.
Also when 2 arc are formed. the shortest one would be ignored.

Comment: moved to math.stackexchange.com as requested 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150539/find-radius-of-fixed-length-arc-of-a-circle-in-a-bounding-box-when-the-circle-in

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible line of attack. Let's put some names:

- `alpha` = angle at which the circle intercepts the horizontal line on the right side
- `r` = radius
- `arc` = length of the "visible" circle (known)
- `L` = length to edge (known) (Let's assume `L` > 0)
- `Pi` the number pi.

Using that `arc = radius * angle` (radians), we have:

```
arc = Pi * r + 2 * alpha * r
sin(alpha) = L / r
```

Solving for `alpha` in the first equation

```
alpha = arc / (2 * r) - Pi / 2
```

Using that `sin(a - b) = sin(a)cos(b) - cos(a)sin(b)`

L / r = sin(alpha) = -cos(arc / (2 * r))

Now put `u = L/r`. Since `L` is known, `u` becomes the unknown. Replacing:

u = -cos(arc / (2 * L) * u)

Finally put `F = arc / (2 * L)`. Then `F` is known and

u = - cos(F * u)

So, the problem reduces to solve this equation, which will require some numerical algorithm.

Comment: This is about as close as you can get. but  turns out over on math. stack its not solvable.

What i have done is created a multiplier and maped the distance from the edge so Y =  0 to 150 and mapped that down to 2 to 1so if Y = 150 the map = 1 and if Y = 0 the map is 2 so if y = 75 then multiplier = 1.5 ect
This mapping is then used as a multiplier
radius = radius * multipler

this gets me close enough...
Then in the corner i do the same thing for X and add the 2 multipler together so if your in the car corner both multiplers = 2 and 
so radius = radius * (multiplerX + MultiplerY)

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is created a multiplier and maped the distance from the edge so Y =  0 to 150 and mapped that down to 2 to 1 so if Y = 150 the map = 1 and if Y = 0 the map is 2 so if y = 75 then the map = 1.5 ect

This mapping is then used as a multiplier
radius = radius * map

This gets me close enough...
Then in the corner i do the same thing for X and add the 2 multiplier together so if you're in the far corner both maps = 2 and 
so radius = radius * (mapX + mapY)

Doubles it on edges and quadruples it in the corners. which is ~ close enough